# sympy + logic module: assert(is_cnf(to_cnf(expr, simplify=True))) fails

Tags: python, sympy, boolean-logic

I'm trying to use sympy to help me parse some logic-related text-files (after additional string-processing: e.g. generation of *numbered x-vars* like `x0, x1...`) and i don't understand the following behaviour:

```
in_ = '( ( x1 & x2 & x3 & x4 & x5 & x6 & x7 & x8 & x9 )  |  ( x1 & x2 & x3 & x4 & x5 & x6 & x7 & x10 & x9 )  |  ( x1 & x11 & x3 & x12 & x5 & x13 & x14 & x15 & x9 ) ) '

from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_cnf, is_cnf

parsed = parse_expr(in_, evaluate=False)
cnf_candidate = to_cnf(parsed, simplify=True)  # broken with simp=True; works with simp=False
cnf_status = is_cnf(cnf_candidate)

print(parsed)
print(cnf_candidate)
print(cnf_status)

assert cnf_status 

> (x1 & x10 & x2 & x3 & x4 & x5 & x6 & x7 & x9) | (x1 & x11 & x12 & x13 & x14 & x15 & x3 & x5 & x9) 
(x1 & x2 & x3 & x4 & x5 & x6 & x7 & x8 & x9)

> (x1 & x10 & x2 & x3 & x4 & x5 & x6 & x7 & x9) | (x1 & x11 & x12 & x13 & x14 & x15 & x3 & x5 & x9) | 
(x1 & x2 & x3 & x4 & x5 & x6 & x7 & x8 & x9)

> False
> AssertionError
```

This looks really bad!

- `to_cnf` does not really produce a cnf and does not warn me about it (with `simplify=True`).

Without simplification:

- it works and the output shows the expected exponential blow-up

This somewhat looks like  a *"i will never be able to minimize that so i don't try it"* thing, **without any feedback**.

Did i miss something? Is my usage correct (i assumed sympys parsing able to work with my numbered variables).

(Let's ignore the more theoretical side for now -> exponential blow-up; feasibility of simplification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_cnf` function with `simplify=True` calls `simplify_logic` without passing the `force=True` flag setting. Since the expresssion has more than 8 variables a conversion to cnf is not attempted and the routine does not check to see if the simplified result is in cnf form. A simple patch is

```
diff --git a/sympy/logic/boolalg.py b/sympy/logic/boolalg.py
index dd734ce..d544ea7 100644
--- a/sympy/logic/boolalg.py
+++ b/sympy/logic/boolalg.py
@@ -1714,7 +1714,9 @@ def to_cnf(expr, simplify=False):
         return expr

     if simplify:
-        return simplify_logic(expr, 'cnf', True)
+        new = simplify_logic(expr, 'cnf', True)
+        if is_cnf(new):
+            return new

     # Don't convert unless we have to
     if is_cnf(expr):
```

Then (if you want to try simplify the result) you have to call `simplify_logic` with `force=True`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Honestly speaking, i do think that this is a terrible design-choice (silent fail). Having invested a few hours now into sympy's logic module, i somewhat doubt it's usefulness for cases like mine (preparing model in combinatorial opt) observing this behaviour, but also missing features like tseitin-encoding (although there might be hidden branches / work on it) or even more simple stuff like `is the literal in my processed term negated?` (don't know how to do that without string-based checking for `~`). Sadly, pyeda is less active and has other problems. Again: thanks.

Comment: ` terrible design-choice` -> human oversight; I'm sure this will be fixed soon.